# IntelliJ test classpath: Different when running class vs package

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have multi module project that has a test module specifically for running integration tests.
I've noticed the test classpath changes significantly when running a single class vs running all the same package.

From inspection I can see another project module (and it's dependencies) are being added to the classpath that is not a dependency of the test module (direct or transitive) - it is fact a database migration library that is not depended on by anything else.

Can anyone rationalise why a test classpath would change when running a single class vs all 3 classes in that same package?

Background:
IntelliJ 14.1.3
Tests pass when running via Maven

Comment: How did you configure the [classpaths](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-application.html#1) for the 2 runs?

Comment: @Morfic Both use the default setting. When running a single test, it defaults to the modules classpath, when running a package the option is greyed out and unmodifiable.

Comment: @Morfic Thanks for the doco link. That got me experimenting and I eventually solved it. So it turns out the default test classpath when running package is EVERYTHING. I had to create a configuration to explicitly set the classpath to for a particular module when running tests from a particular package. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. Add an answer to claim your points!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Although I feel that you should post and accept your own answer as you did most of the work :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference could be seen in the `Run...` Run Configurations sections.

When using the `Run...` option for a package, the `Test kind` defaults to All in Package however the `Package` does not default to the package used when invoking `Run...`. The default `Use classpath of module` was greyed out (and will remain that way until you select a `Package`), so it looks like the classpath of all modules was used.

`Use classpath of module` was the option I needed to correct the classpath when running all tests in a package.

[image]